# Writing udf function in scala and using them in pyspark job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

We are trying to write a scala udf function and call it from a map function in pyspark. The dateframe schema is quite complex the columns we want to pass to this function are array of StructType.

`trip_force_speeds = trip_details.groupby("vehicle_id","driver_id", "StartDtLocal", "EndDtLocal")\
                                    .agg(collect_list(struct(col("event_start_dt_local"), 
                                                            col("force"), 
                                                            col("speed"), 
                                                            col("sec_from_start"), 
                                                            col("sec_from_end"), 
                                                            col("StartDtLocal"), 
                                                            col("EndDtLocal"), 
                                                            col("verisk_vehicle_id"), 
                                                            col("trip_duration_sec")))\
                                    .alias("trip_details"))`

In our map function we need to do some computation.

```
def calculateVariables(rec: Row):HashMap[String,Float] = {
val trips = rec.getAs[List]("trips")
val base_variables = new HashMap[String, Float]()   

val entropy_variables = new HashMap[String, Float]()

val week_day_list = List("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday")

for (trip <- trips)
{
  if (trip("start_dt_local") >= trip("StartDtLocal") && trip("start_dt_local") <= trip("EndDtLocal"))
  {
    base_variables("trip_summary_count") += 1

    if (trip("duration_sec").toFloat >= 300 && trip("duration_sec").toFloat <= 1800) {
      base_variables ("bounded_trip") +=  1

      base_variables("bounded_trip_duration") = trip("duration_sec") + base_variables("bounded_trip_duration")

      base_variables("total_bin_1") += 30

      base_variables("total_bin_2") += 30

      base_variables("total_bin_3") += 60

      base_variables("total_bin_5") += 60

      base_variables("total_bin_6") += 30

      base_variables("total_bin_7") += 30
    }
    if (trip("duration_sec") > 120 && trip("duration_sec") < 21600 )
    {
      base_variables("trip_count") += 1
    }

    base_variables("trip_distance") += trip("distance_km")

    base_variables("trip_duration") = trip("duration_sec") + base_variables("trip_duration")

    base_variables("speed_event_distance") = trip("speed_event_distance_km")  + base_variables("speed_event_distance")

    base_variables("speed_event_duration") = trip("speed_event_duration_sec") + base_variables("speed_event_duration")

    base_variables("speed_event_distance_ratio") = trip("speed_distance_ratio") + base_variables("speed_event_distance_ratio")

    base_variables("speed_event_duration_ratio") = trip("speed_duration_ratio") + base_variables("speed_event_duration_ratio")

  }
}
return base_variables
}
```

when we tried to compile the scala code we got thie error

i tried using Row but got this error

> "error: kinds of the type arguments (List) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type T). List's type parameters do not match type T's expected parameters: type List has one type parameter, but type T has none – "

in my case the trip is a list of rows. this is the schema

```
StructType(List(StructField(verisk_vehicle_id,StringType,true),StructField(verisk_driver_id,StringType,false),StructField(StartDtLocal,TimestampType,true),StructField(EndDtLocal,TimestampType,true),StructField(trips,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(week_start_dt_local,TimestampType,true),StructField(week_end_dt_local,TimestampType,true),StructField(start_dt_local,TimestampType,true),StructField(end_dt_local,TimestampType,true),StructField(StartDtLocal,TimestampType,true),StructField(EndDtLocal,TimestampType,true),StructField(verisk_vehicle_id,StringType,true),StructField(duration_sec,FloatType,true),StructField(distance_km,FloatType,true),StructField(speed_distance_ratio,FloatType,true),StructField(speed_duration_ratio,FloatType,true),StructField(speed_event_distance_km,FloatType,true),StructField(speed_event_duration_sec,FloatType,true))),true),true),StructField(trip_details,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(event_start_dt_local,TimestampType,true),StructField(force,FloatType,true),StructField(speed,FloatType,true),StructField(sec_from_start,FloatType,true),StructField(sec_from_end,FloatType,true),StructField(StartDtLocal,TimestampType,true),StructField(EndDtLocal,TimestampType,true),StructField(verisk_vehicle_id,StringType,true),StructField(trip_duration_sec,FloatType,true))),true),true)))
```

is there something wrong in the way we defined the function signature we tried overriding the spark structtype but that didn't work for me.

i am from a python background and am facing some performance issues in python job, that's why i decided to write this map function in Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must work with the Row type instead of the StructType in your udf. StructType represents the schema itself not the data. A little example in Scala that you can use:

```
object test{

  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, collect_list, struct}

  val hash = HashMap[String, Float]("start_dt_local" -> 0)
  // This simple type to store you results
  val sampleDataset = Seq(Row(Instant.now().toEpochMilli, Instant.now().toEpochMilli))

  implicit val spark: SparkSession =
    SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Test")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

  def calculateVariablesUdf = udf { trip: Row =>

    if(trip.getAs[Long]("start_dt_local") >= trip.getAs[Long]("StartDtLocal")) {
      // crate a new instance with your results
      hash("start_dt_local") + 1
    } else {
      hash("start_dt_local") + 0
    }

  }


  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)

    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(sampleDataset)
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, StructType(List(StructField("start_dt_local", LongType, false), StructField("StartDtLocal", LongType, false))))

    df.agg(collect_list(calculateVariablesUdf(struct(col("start_dt_local"), col("StartDtLocal")))).as("result")).show(false)

  }
}
```

Edit. For a better understanding:

You are wrong when you consider a schema description: StructType(List(StructField)) as the type of your field. There is not List type in your DataFrame.

If you treat your calculateVariables as an udf you don´t need the for loop. I mean:

```
def calculateVariables = udf { trip: Row =>
  trip("start_dt_local").getAs[Long] 
  // your logic ....

}
```

As I put in the example you can return your updated Hash directly in the udf

Comment: Done. You can use java.sql.Timestamp to deal with your timestamp types. And the error with List is because List Type in Scala is a hinder kinded type so you need to declared the type of the elements of the list: List[Int][ or List[String], etc ...